# Oracle cascade select

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I want to get data from a set of tables in a cascade way for a given predicate.

As an example, there is a parent table which has customer information (i.e. CustomerID) and then there would be 10s of child tables. I want to select data from a limited number of child tables for that customer (or even selecting from all child tables is not a super bad idea).

I can totally start a transaction and query all the tables specifically for that customer but I am looking for a cascade query to select all the objects in one query like Oracle has cascade delete.

Is it possible to achieve that? If yes, how?

Comment: This seems very inefficient. Why do you want to do that instead of writing a query to get you specifically what you are after?

Answer (score 3):

No.  You would have to write the code yourself (hard-coded) or have code generate the code based on data dictionary traversal of the FK/PK constraints.